# Flex - Dispatch custom Event on receipt of standard Event

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, filereferencelist

I am processing a FileReferenceList.fileList[] of multiple files a user selects in the following code..

```
for (i=0;i < event.currentTarget.fileList.length; i ++){
 fileByteData = new ByteArray();
 fileByteData = (event.currentTarget.fileList[i].data as ByteArray);                
 loader = new Loader();
 loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, checkImageDimensions);
 loader.loadBytes(fileByteData);                    
}
```

I need to pass i into checkImageDimensions to keep track of which image is which, I can easily enough create a custom event, but I need this to fire at the right time. Ideally I could do something like this..

```
var myEvent:CustomEvent = new CustomEvent(i);
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, this.dispatchEvent(CustomEvent))
```

But to be honest, I am unsure of how to proceed...

Can anyone help me out? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make a listener function - a function call does not suffice.  Passing a class name to `dispatchEvent` does not work either.  Here's how to do it.

```
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(e:Event):void {
    dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(i));
});
```

Note that you don't necessarily need a custom event class, if all you need in the event is a type string.  You can simply use the Event class in this case:

```
public static const MY_CUSTOM_EVENT:String = "myCustomEvent";    
...
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(e:Event):void {
    dispatchEvent(new Event(MY_CUSTOM_EVENT));
});
```

**Edit**: If you're really lazy, but still want to pass values with the event, you can use the `DinamicEvent` class:

```
var evt:DynamicEvent = new DynamicEvent(MY_CUSTOM_EVENT);
evt.attr1 = val1;
evt.attr2 = val2;
dispatchEvent(evt);
```

Of course, it is cleaner and less error prone to declare your own error class.

Comment: I need to pass an integer along with every different event, in case they fire in a different order. I don't see how I can do this with your second method? Thanks for the hint though!